# How to add toggle, switch button in WIDGET

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I want to add toggle button and switch in app widget. How can I add them?  I do not understand how to assign button id. Normaly we use `FindViewById` but what should I use in a widget?

```
Togglebutton a = (TB) FindViewById(R.ID.xyz)
```

I also added one text view widget and now I want when I click on it to update that TextView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ToggleButton is not supported on widgets, use instead an ImageView (change image source dynamically).

Comment: Hw I can assign image I'd?

Comment: youImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_imgtoLoad)

Comment: how i can get battery level

Comment: check this link : http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/getting-battery-information-on-android.html

Comment: Android 12 starts supporting switches, checkboxes and radio buttons: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/features/widgets